# javascript sort an array of words based on weights from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of strings and weights associated with it as below:

```
const words = ['abcd', 'aecd', 'abaa', 'abef', 'acdcc', 'acbcc'];
let weights = [2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 5];
```

I want to sort the words based on their weights in another array in decreasing order. I tried the solution below:

```
words.sort((a, b) =>
    weights.indexOf(b) -
    weights.indexOf(a));
```

Could anyone pls suggest an alternative solution.

thanks

Comment: `weights.indexOf(...)` makes no sense, none of these words _are_ anywhere in `weights`.

Comment: You would need to use `weights[words.indexOf(...)]` to find the number in `weights`, that _corresponds_ to your given word, by _its_ index position. (That will only work as long as the words are unique.)

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to approach this would be to combine the words and weights into a single array, then sort that array.

```js
const words = ['abcd', 'aecd', 'abaa', 'abef', 'acdcc', 'acbcc'];
const weights = [2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 5];

const result = words
  .map((word, i) => ({ word, weight: weights[i] }))
  .sort((a, b) => a.weight - b.weight)
  .map(({ word }) => word);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `weights[words.indexOf(b)]`, not `weights.indexOf(b)` (although this will only work if the values in `words` are unique):

```js
const words = ['abcd', 'aecd', 'abaa', 'abef', 'acdcc', 'acbcc'];
let weights = [2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 5];

words.sort((a, b) =>
  weights[words.indexOf(b)] -
  weights[words.indexOf(a)]);

console.log(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand in detail how things works please refer below code.

```js
const words = ['abcd', 'aecd', 'abaa', 'abef', 'acdcc', 'acbcc'];
let weights = [2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 5];
var weights1 = [];
let words1 = []; 
weights.forEach(function(a) {
   weights1.push(a);
});
weights.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
});
weights.forEach(function(a) {
  words1.push(words[weights1.indexOf(a)]);
});

console.log(words1);
```